# How to make bootable USB with Linux Kernel alone?

Tags: linux, boot, kernel, usb-storage

I would like to boot the Linux kernel alone and run busybox, not including a GUI.

How can I do that? How can I make a custom `bzImage`, `initrd.img` and how can I change the file structures in that images?

Comment: alone is alone. with busybox it is not alone.

Answer (score 5):

This might help you: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/  You can customize as per you want.

Answer (score 3):

Two things you need to do:

1. Build a custom kernel and an initrd image
2. Make a bootable USB containing the above

For the first part, you are best using the "genkernel" tool. You can probably achieve what you want by issuing `genkernel --menuconfig all`. This will allow you to first configure the kernel, then build it together with modules (if any) and a ramdisk image (initrd/initramfs).

However, if you have never built a custom kernel, bear in mind that kernel configuration is not an easy task. You're best staying with as many defaults as you can.

After that step, you'll find your kernel image and initramfs under `/boot/` - they will be named something like `kernel-genkernel-<something_including_your_kernel_version>` and `initramfs-genkernel-<the_same_ending>`.

Once you have that, you can go for building your custom bootable USB stick containing the files. To do that, I'd recommend following the [Gentoo Linux documentation](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/liveusb.xml), replacing `emerge` with the appropriate package manager command for your distribution.